# Why do multiple images on canvas not load in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I just can't figure out on how should I approach this strict WebKit.
So I have multiple images that I am loading in the canvas but the problem is in Google's Chrome browser is it does not load because of the strict WebKit based on my research and the only way to make it work is to have a logic of "*pre-loading*" the images. Can you give me some ideas on how should I approach this or aybe some code snippets?

I have here my code that has the solutions I found on the net and implemented:

```
var vCanvas, vContext;
// Chap02 Backgrounds
//var officeBG;
// GUIs
var episode, logo, name, dialogue, nextBTN, backBTN, menuBTN, epiBTN, audioBTN, quitBTN;

// Solution 1 = Not Working
/*var episode = new Image();
var logo = new Image();
var name = new Image();
var dialogue = new Image();
var nextBTN = new Image();
var backBTN = new Image();
var menuBTN = new Image();
var epiBTN = new Image();
var audioBTN = new Image();
var quitBTN = new Image();*/

// Solution 2 = Not Working
/*var test = new Array();
test[0] = new Image();
test[0].src = './gameGUI/Episode.png';
test[1] = new Image();
test[1].src = './gameGUI/Logo.png';
test[2] = new Image();
test[2].src = './gameGUI/Name.png';
test[3] = new Image();
test[3].src = './gameGUI/Dialogue.png';
test[4] = new Image();
test[4].src = './gameGUI/NextBtn.png';
test[5] = new Image();
test[5].src = './gameGUI/BackBtn.png';
test[6] = new Image();
test[6].src = './gameGUI/MenuBtn.png';
test[7] = new Image();
test[7].src = './gameGUI/EpisodesBtn.png';
test[8] = new Image();
test[8].src = './gameGUI/AudioBtn.png';
test[9] = new Image();
test[9].src = './gameGUI/QuitBtn.png';*/


// First Function to load all the magic stuff
function load() {
    vCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    vContext = vCanvas.getContext("2d");
    officeBG = document.getElementById("officeBG");
    vContext.drawImage(officeBG, 0, 0);

    InGameGUI();
}

// Function to clear the canvas
function clearCanvas() {
    vContext.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 480);
}

function InGameGUI() {
    // Default that shows up properly on Firefox
    episode = document.getElementById("episode");
    logo = document.getElementById("logo");
    name = document.getElementById("name");
    dialogue = document.getElementById("dialogue");
    nextBTN = document.getElementById("nextBTN");
    backBTN = document.getElementById("backBTN");
    menuBTN = document.getElementById("menuBTN");
    epiBTN = document.getElementById("epiBTN");
    audioBTN = document.getElementById("audioBTN");
    quitBTN = document.getElementById("quitBTN");

    vContext.drawImage(episode, 0, 0, 216, 39, 15, 13, 216, 39);
    vContext.drawImage(logo, 0, 0, 143, 86, 647, 10, 143, 86);
    vContext.drawImage(name, 0, 0, 484, 33, 0, 293, 484, 33);
    vContext.drawImage(dialogue, 0, 0, 800, 154, 0, 326, 800, 154);
    vContext.drawImage(nextBTN, 0, 0, 83, 39, 685, 355, 83, 39);
    vContext.drawImage(backBTN, 0, 0, 56, 27, 697, 403, 56, 27);
    vContext.drawImage(menuBTN, 0, 0, 54, 27, 473, 452, 54, 27);
    vContext.drawImage(epiBTN, 0, 0, 77, 25, 540, 452, 77, 25);
    vContext.drawImage(audioBTN, 0, 0, 54, 27, 636, 452, 54, 27);
    vContext.drawImage(quitBTN, 0, 0, 54, 27, 733, 452, 54, 27);

    // Solution 1
    /*episode.onload = vContext.drawImage(episode, 0, 0, 216, 39, 15, 13, 216, 39);
    logo.onload = vContext.drawImage(logo, 0, 0, 143, 86, 647, 10, 143, 86);
    name.onload = vContext.drawImage(name, 0, 0, 484, 33, 0, 293, 484, 33);
    dialogue.onload = vContext.drawImage(dialogue, 0, 0, 800, 154, 0, 326, 800, 154);
    nextBTN.onload = vContext.drawImage(nextBTN, 0, 0, 83, 39, 685, 355, 83, 39);
    backBTN.onload = vContext.drawImage(backBTN, 0, 0, 56, 27, 697, 403, 56, 27);
    menuBTN.onload = vContext.drawImage(menuBTN, 0, 0, 54, 27, 473, 452, 54, 27);
    epiBTN.onload = vContext.drawImage(epiBTN, 0, 0, 77, 25, 540, 452, 77, 25);
    audioBTN.onload = vContext.drawImage(audioBTN, 0, 0, 54, 27, 636, 452, 54, 27);
    quitBTN.onload = vContext.drawImage(quitBTN, 0, 0, 54, 27, 733, 452, 54, 27);*/

    // Solution 2
    /*test[0].onload = function(){ vContext.drawImage(episode, 0, 0, 216, 39, 15, 13, 216, 39); };
    test[1].onload = function(){ vContext.drawImage(logo, 0, 0, 143, 86, 647, 10, 143, 86); };*/
}

// Solution 3 = Not Working
/*function loadImages(sources, callback) {
  var images = {};
  var loadedImages = 0;
  var numImages = 0;
  // get num of sources
  for(var src in sources) {
    numImages++;
  }
  for(var src in sources) {
    images[src] = new Image();
    images[src].onload = function() {
      if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
        callback(images);
      }
    };
    images[src].src = sources[src];
  }
}
var vCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var vContext = vCanvas.getContext('2d');

var sources = {
        episode: './gameGUI/Episode.png',
        logo: './gameGUI/Logo.png',
        name: './gameGUI/Name.png',
        dialogue: './gameGUI/Dialogue.png',
        nextBTN: './gameGUI/NextBtn.png',
        backBTN: './gameGUI/BackBtn.png',
        menuBTN: './gameGUI/MenuBtn.png',
        epiBTN: './gameGUI/EpisodesBtn.png',
        audioBTN: './gameGUI/AudiBtn.png',
        quitBTN: './gameGUI/QuitBtn.png'
};

loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    vContext.drawImage(images.logo, 0, 0, 143, 86, 647, 10, 143, 86);
    vContext.drawImage(images.name, 0, 0, 484, 33, 0, 293, 484, 33);
    vContext.drawImage(images.dialogue, 0, 0, 800, 154, 0, 326, 800, 154);
    vContext.drawImage(images.nextBTN, 0, 0, 83, 39, 685, 355, 83, 39);
    vContext.drawImage(images.backBTN, 0, 0, 56, 27, 697, 403, 56, 27);
    vContext.drawImage(images.menuBTN, 0, 0, 54, 27, 473, 452, 54, 27);
    vContext.drawImage(images.epiBTN, 0, 0, 77, 25, 540, 452, 77, 25);
    vContext.drawImage(images.audioBTN, 0, 0, 54, 27, 636, 452, 54, 27);
    vContext.drawImage(images.quitBTN, 0, 0, 54, 27, 733, 452, 54, 27);
});*/

addEventListener("load", load, false);
```

Is there a way I can solution this using only javascript without JQuery or I really need to use JQuery to *preload* the images.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a javascript-only image loader you can use.

When all the images are loaded the start() function is called.

You can begin drawImage, etc in start()

```
// image loader

var imageURLs=[]; 
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];

// put the paths to your images here
imageURLs.push("./gameGUI/Episode.png");
imageURLs.push("./gameGUI/Logo.png");
// ... same with all your other images

loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}
```

var episode,logo;  // and a var for all the other image objects

```
function start(){

    // At this point...
    // the imgs[] array holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

    // drawImage the episode
    vContext.drawImage(imgs[0], 0, 0, 216, 39, 15, 13, 216, 39);

    // drawImage the logo
    vContext.drawImage(imgs[1], 0, 0, 143, 86, 647, 10, 143, 86);


}
```

Comment: `imageURLs.push` for the path of the images are written correctly. `.drawImage` of `imgs[2]` to `imgs[9]` was also correctly coded. But now, Chrome won't load any of the images but in Firefox it shows 2 alert messages of `img.onerror` then loads all the images fine.

Comment: OK, we need to narrow down the failing URLs. Replace `function(){alert("image load failed");} ` with `function(){alert("image load failed: "+this.src);}`.  That will tell you which 2 images are failing to load.  Then check for typos in those URLs or investigate why they won't load.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

> ```
> // flag showing whether a loop through the image list is finished, 
> //needed because loading will be finished in a time after looping 
> var _loop_finished = false;
>
> /* number of loaded images */
> var _loadedNum = 0;
> var _images = {};
>
> function Load(list, callback) {
>   var createdNum = 0;
>   for ( var i in list ) {
>       _createdNum++;
>   }
>
>   for ( var key in list ) {
>       if ( list.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
>           var image = new Image();
>           image.key = key;
>           image.src = list[key];
>
>           _images[key] = image;
>
>           image.onload = function () {
>               _loadedNum++;
>
>               console.log("Cached image '" + this.key + "'");
>
>               if ( _loop_finished == true && createdNum == _loadedNum ) {
>                   if ( callback != null ) {
>                       callback();
>                   }
>               }
>           };
>       }
>   }
>
>   _loop_finished = true;
>   return this;
> };
> ```

```
 Load({a: './images/a.png', b: './images/b.png'}, function() {

    //will be executed after images are loaded
    // console.log(_images.a);
    //
});
```